# Rails: Active Record Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have the following models:

```
require 'books_projects.rb'

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_to_projects
  has_many :books, :through => :book_to_projects
end

require 'books_projects.rb'

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_to_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :book_to_projects
end
```

books_projects.rb:

```
class BookToProject < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "books_projects"
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :project
end
```

In my projects controller, I am trying to do this:

```
@projects = Project.find(:all, :include => [:books])
```

My hope is to get a nested data structure back that looks something like:

```
projects: [
  {
    ..,
    books: [
        {
          ..
        },
        {
          ..
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

This doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Also, does the above model relationship call for the use of `has_and_belongs_to_many` in project and book instead of specifying the join table?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**
I don't have a view. This acts like a REST service only. I am doing the following:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.find(:all, :include => [:books])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @projects }
    format.json { render :json => @projects}
  end
end
```

This does not produce the output that I'm looking for (mentioned above).

Comment: Well it should work! try <%=debug @project %> in your view, you should see a yaml representation of your object with the books included

Comment: If `book_projects` doesn't have any other attributes, then yes, use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Furthermore I agree with charlysisto: it *should* work? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Can I ask why you are "going against the grain"? Why do you have a file `book_projects.rb` which defines `BookToProject`, yet the table name is `book_projects`? Why are you requiring this file from your other two models? You should only have to require it once somewhere in your project, but why are you requiring at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that the following works:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @projects.to_json(:include => [:books]) }
  end
end
```

Can someone tell me why this works and the one before didn't?

Comment: If this works, you should mark it as the correct answer. That being said, it seems like `to_json` will not include associations by default, hence why it didn't work before and you needed to explicitly include them.

Comment: Aah! Thanks! Yeah I'll mark it in about 3 hours from now. It doesn't let me do so right now..

Answer (score 1):

You code does exactly what you expect it to do. The problem is in verifying that.

Try this:

```
project = Project.find(:first)
project.books.loaded?
```

would return false

```
project = Project.find(:first, :include => [:books])
project.books.loaded?
```

would return true :)

The eager-loaded associations do not normally show up when you inspect the object.